# Get all active policies for a particular month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table PolicyStatusLog as shown below:

| IdPolicyStatusLog | IdPolicy | IdStatusChangedFrom | IdStatusChangedTo | DateChanged |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28834 | 24142 | 3 | 10 | 2020-11-19 |
| 28847 | 24142 | 10 | 1 | 2020-11-20 |

If the last IdStatusChangedTo of a Policy is 1, then the Policy is still active.

Let's say I want to get all active policies(i.e IdPolicys) for the month of January. This will include polices where the status was last changed to active(i.e 1) before or during  January.

I hope I explained the problem clearly, but I can always give more details as required.

How do I write a query for this in SQL? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't tag conflicting technologies.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik Sql server

Comment: What did you try? because this seems to be a very basic SQL question.

Comment: What results do you want? Just the policy ids? Also the last change date? Something else? Do you have a policy table, with one row per policy? You should do, and it will make the query significantly simpler and cheaper to run. Finally, please don't include images, the editor in SO allows you to format text as code or tables. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Luuk I tried getting all active policies before January, but then I didn't know how to filter out policies where the status was later changed from 1 to something else.

Comment: Providing data instead of images of it helps to get much faster recommendations from the community.it is one of the reasons that you get Downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a policy table...

Get the latest `PolicyStatusLog` record (prior to Feb 1st) for each policy, and keep only policies where the latest status is. 1.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  policy    AS p
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM PolicyStatusLog
   WHERE IDPolicy = policy.ID
     AND DateChanged < '2022-02-01'
ORDER BY DateChanged DESC
)
  AS s
WHERE
  s.IdStatusChangedTo = 1
```

Assumes all policies have at least one row in the log. For example, if there's a new policy, is there an initial row in the log with status 1?